# PROBLEMA CON double y float JAVA

Tags: java, android

Tengo este problema que no he encontrado una manera de solucionarlo. El error se da justo en "siguiente"

el codigo primera parte

```
 etvalor.setText(min);
Double Bsf = Double.parseDouble(tasa)*s;
           Bsf = Double.parseDouble(tasa)*s;
                Locale currentLocale = Locale.GERMAN;
                otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
                otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
                otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');

                df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", otherSymbols);
                String numberAsString = df.format(Bsf);
                etBsf.setText(numberAsString);
                etBsfpromo.setText(numberAsString);
```

luego

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   Double w = null;
   try {
       if(checkboxpromo.isChecked()){
           w = etvalor.getCurrencyDouble()*(1+(Double.parseDouble(valorp.get(spinnerpromo.getSelectedItemPosition()))/100));
                            valorpromo = valorp.get(spinnerpromo.getSelectedItemPosition());

          }else {
              w = etvalor.getCurrencyDouble();
              valorpromo = "0";
                   }
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha ocurrido un error111", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
               double w1 = Double.parseDouble(finalTasa)*w;
               String numberAsString3 = df.format(w1);
                etBsf.setText(numberAsString3);
                etBsfpromo.setText(numberAsString3);  
                }
```

código donde me presenta el error

```
public void siguiente(View v) throws ParseException {
    int b = 0;
    Double valor = etvalor.getCurrencyDouble();
    float valor2 = Float.parseFloat(min);
    df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00", otherSymbols);
    String min_format = df.format(Float.parseFloat(min));

    if (valor < valor2) {
        etvalor.setError("El monto mínimo es: "+min_format);
    }else{
        etvalor.setError(null);
    }

        if(checkboxpromo.isChecked()){
            check1 = "Yes";
        }else{
            check1 = "No";
        }
        SharedPreferences loginprefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = loginprefs.edit();
        editor.putString("timer", String.valueOf(remaining));
        editor.commit();
        Intent paso3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), public_reg3.class);
        paso3.putExtra("tasa",tasa);
        paso3.putExtra("min",min);
        paso3.putExtra("valorp",valorpromo);
        paso3.putExtra("divisas",valor.toString());
        paso3.putExtra("check1",check1);
        startActivity(paso3);


    }
}
```

Este sería el error que se me muestra en logcat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos numéricos obtenidos de la base de datos a través de php son del tipo float y los que se almacenan serán del tipo decimal.

La  linea especifica 1401 se refiere a la parte del codigo escrito previamente.

```
    Double valor = etvalor.getCurrencyDouble();
```

No sé mucho sobre java, cualquier aporte se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Es una excepción tipo ``NumberFormatException`` que inicia  en la línea 538.  El stack indica que hay un problema con el String " 1500" , ya que hay un espacio y no logra hacer el parseo (Double) , podrías usar la función ``"Aquí tu cadena numérica".trim()`` para eliminar el espacio en blanco.

Comment: Comprendo. Realmente es 1500 es un 15,00. Alguna otra sugerencia que se te ocurra @FernandoCarraro?

Comment: Si dices que el valor es quince con 00, y te está llegando como mil quinientos **realmente**, entonces, tendrías que verificar por qué te está llegando así. El primer paso, dado que dices que los datos vienen de una base de datos en PHP, sería que nos digas, de qué tipo es ese dato allí y en segundo lugar, que verifiques (usando `Log.d` o de otro modo) cómo llega ese dato a Android. En cuanto al código Java, veo que mezclas `Decimal` y `Float` manejando los datos. Si se trata de valores monetarios, usa `Decimal` y olvida `Float` totalmente, no es adecuado para manejar  valores monetarios.

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal esta especificado aquí:

> NumberFormatException : For input string: " 1500"

El problema es que al tratar de convertir la cadena esta no parece ser un valor numérico debido a el espacio que tiene al inicio.

Antes de convertir el valor elimina los espacios en los extremos de la cadena usando la función `.trim()` :

```
 min = min.trim()
 float valor2 = Float.parseFloat(min);
```